# Present perfect continue & perfect

Tags: tenses, present-perfect, future

Could anyone tell me if my examples below is correct, I mean, tenses?

1. "In fact, I've been thinking about keeping this path when **I've finished** business school..."
2. "In fact, I've been thinking about keeping this path when **I finish** business school...."

*I wanted to say : when I have finished my school => future*

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example 1 could be improved like this:

> "In fact, I've been thinking about **staying on this path after** I've finished business school..."

Example 2 could be improved like this:

> "In fact, I've been thinking about **staying on this path** when [or after] I finish business school..."

Example 1 really needs the conjunctive adverb "after" to agree with the future time period contained in "have finished." Additionally, "keeping this path" sounds odd to my native-speaking ears, thus my suggestion for "staying on this path."